# Div disappears when set position: fixed

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm facing a problem with the position: fixed. I don't know why when I set the body is fixed, my header disappears, Can you explain for me why and tell solution of it

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.6);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

when I set position: relative
[image]

And when I set position: fixed
[image]

Comment: Please show enough code so we can reproduce the problem. In particular how is the header positioned and what is the relevant HTML structure?

Comment: A body, as the most outer element should not be fixed or absolute, because there must be a relative parent as a reference to calculate the fixed and absolute position inside. This can lead to unexpected behavior in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the body to position:relative and in a new div inside the body
add your code

```
.myclass{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.6);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```